# Expanding fluid

Tags: fluid-simulation

Almost all tutorials with fluid have the fluid in gravitational field, so that you can see it splashing around.

But is there some way to create a thick fluid coming out of the source and pushing the surface outwards. Al in no gravity.

I would like to see how a cavity fills up from a point. Maybe smoke is better? But It's hard to guess and read about the all the parameters

EDIT: It doesn't appear the the fluid particles push at each other. Which seems essential for simulating pressure. But maybe I missed something

Comment: Have you tried using particles set to 'Fluid' in the Physics properties? It might need some tweaking to the various settings but might be suitable for your needs. Can you update your question with some images showing what kind of cavities you're looking to fill?

Comment: I check ot out. Thanks. I woyld like to try with several different cavities. This is not a art project, but a test to see how a fluid will spread from a point in the cavitu.